# generate all quadratic combinations of any 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` `df` with columns `C1`, `C2`, `C3`, `C4`.  I want a new `DataFrame` in which every combination of one column multiplied with the other is represented.  This means in the case of 4 columns to start with, we should have `sum(4, 3, 2, 1) = 10` columns.  Furthermore, the columns should be labeled as a `MultiIndex` where each level identifies one of the original columns being multiplied.

So if

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 4) * 10, columns=['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4']).astype(int)

print df

   C1  C2  C3  C4
0   8   0   5   6
1   4   5   3   5
```

I expect `df_quad` to look like:

```
   C1              C2          C3      C4
   C1  C2  C3  C4  C2  C3  C4  C3  C4  C4
0  64   0  40  48   0   0   0  25  30  36
1  16  20  12  20  25  15  25   9  15  25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
from itertools import combinations, combinations_with_replacement

data = """\
   C1  C2  C3  C4
0   8   0   5   6
1   4   5   3   5
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=0)

combs = list(combinations_with_replacement(df.columns.tolist(), 2))

df_quad = pd.DataFrame()

for tup in combs:
   df_quad['{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format(tup)] = df[tup[0]] * df[tup[1]]
```

Test:

```
In [77]: df_quad
Out[77]:
   C1_C1  C1_C2  C1_C3  C1_C4  C2_C2  C2_C3  C2_C4  C3_C3  C3_C4  C4_C4
0     64      0     40     48      0      0      0     25     30     36
1     16     20     12     20     25     15     25      9     15     25

In [156]: df_quad.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combs)

In [157]: df_quad
Out[157]:
   C1              C2          C3      C4
   C1  C2  C3  C4  C2  C3  C4  C3  C4  C4
0  64   0  40  48   0   0   0  25  30  36
1  16  20  12  20  25  15  25   9  15  25

In [78]: combs
Out[78]:
[('C1', 'C1'),
 ('C1', 'C2'),
 ('C1', 'C3'),
 ('C1', 'C4'),
 ('C2', 'C2'),
 ('C2', 'C3'),
 ('C2', 'C4'),
 ('C3', 'C3'),
 ('C3', 'C4'),
 ('C4', 'C4')]
```

Comment: That is interesting.  You taught me a new trick.  However, combinations leaves out the C1_C1 products.  Also, I wanted a MultiIndex, but that parts easy (so I say).

Comment: @piRSquared, i've already noticed that and updated my answer ;)

Comment: You could even `cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combs)` then `df_quad = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)` then `for col in df_quad.columns: df_quad[col] = df[col[0]] * df[col[1]]` <---- Untested.  Just winging it.  But you get the idea.

Comment: @piRSquared, it's a good idea! But it needs to be debuged, it produces an empty DF

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

```
def quadratic_combinations(df):
    rng = range(len(df.columns))
    return pd.concat([df.iloc[:, i:].mul(df.iloc[:, i], axis=0) for i in rng],
                     axis=1, keys=df.columns)

df_quad = quadratic_combinations(df)

print df_quad

   C1              C2          C3      C4
   C1  C2  C3  C4  C2  C3  C4  C3  C4  C4
0  64   0  40  48   0   0   0  25  30  36
1  16  20  12  20  25  15  25   9  15  25
```